# JQuery.post() performs a GET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jersey

I'm using `$.post()` to do the following...

```
    $.post('login',details);
```

I would assume this POST's the data to `login` but all I can see happening is the details being attached to the url as if it's doing a GET request to the page I'm on rather than a POST to my `login` page. Why would this be happening? My `login` page is meant to redirect the user to a new page once their login request has completed so ideally I'd like the POST to go to the `login` page so that the user can be redirected.

The `details` contents are `{ username: "username", pasword: "password"}` and the `login` page is a `login.java` page which is using Jersey.

Comment: Are you using Firebug or something similar to see the request headers, does it give you any errors? Is your JQuery statement properly formatted? $.post("login.php", { login: "John", pass: "XXXX" } );

Comment: Can you show us the resulting URL and the contents of the `details` string? That shouldn't be happening (and I just verified that `$.post` works as expected on my machine in Chrome).

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect your requests. Also I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

POST to GET is often caused by you using a wrong URL.

I think your serverside program is expecting that the URL ends in / and redirects to that address using HTTP 301 or 302 response; according to specs this means that GET must be issued instead of POST.

Try using "login/" instead; also consider that your code should be callable from any url on your site; preferably anchor the urls to server root, thus "/login/"!

Comment: Your address says the page is not found, in the "OR" part. However there is no "defaulting to GET", it only happens as a response to the server issuing a redirect. If no redirect occurs, neither does any request type conversion occur.

Comment: So, basically it defaults to a GET when there is no server redirection

Comment: No, there is no default. If the client makes a POST to /login, but the server wants to canonicalize that to /login/, the server responds with 302 FOUND; Location: /login/. However, browser would not issue another POST, but it would GET /login/ giving the data as querystring.

Answer (score 1):

If $.post don't works, try the $.ajax function instead:

```
    $('#target').click(function() {

    var formdata = $('#loginFrm').serialize(); // will produce { username: "username", pasword: "password"}
        $.ajax({type: "POST",
                        url: "urlto/tojavapage",
                        data: formdata ,
                        success: function(data) {
                            // div container to display error msg       
                            $('#loginmessage').html(data);
                        }
                    });

                    return false;


});`
```

make sure your submit button has a click event that call this e.g

```
<input type="button" value="login" id="target" /> <div id="loginmessage"> </div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this from your home computer, chances are you don't have PHP installed on your computer. This means that the browser treats the post as a normal server request. The other possibility is that you have a form looks something like this

```
<form name="xxx" method="post" action="login">
<!--Stuff-->
<input type="submit" value="xxx" />
</form>
```

this means that the form is going to be submitted without first being screened by jQuery and the browser will once again start looking for a documennt that is not there and do a default `GET` request.

#### Or...

The file you are `POST`ing too is not called index.php or index.html, so the browser finds nothing, and again, defaults to `GET`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of is that if you are collecting the 'details' in a form, and using the onClick handler of the form's submit button to invoke the ajax post,
then the form may be getting submitted before the ajax can actually be invoked.

You should be able to see this by using firebug or the chrome js debugger to put a breakpoint on your $.post call, to see if it gets hit. Or use the tried-and-true method of putting an alert() just before it.